# Version control and frequent merge conflicts with auto-generated xml designer files

Tags: version-control, orm, mercurial, merge

We regularly have lots of conflicts when merging the auto-generated xml files created by using an ORM's designer.

Currently we're using `Mindscape's Lightspeed` and `Mercurial`.  We need the auto-generated xml files in version control, but have to deal with huge numbers of conflicts with the xml files whenever we update.

**Does anyone have any tips for using designers which generate xml without causing loads of conflicts when using version control?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normalize the files in the repository using an [encode](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#decode-encode) filter. You would need to find some XML pretty printer and let it encode the XML files consistently when they are saved into the repository.

You can also configure a custom merge tool for the XML files. That tool can then normalize the three input files before it calls out to another merge tool.